External display arrangement not preserved across reboot in settings in 24.04
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.01. I have a laptop with two external displays.
I went into Settings/Displays, swapped the left-to-right ordering of the external monitors, and applied the configuration, which worked fine.
However, after rebooting, the arrangement is incorrect again and has to be readjusted.

Both monitors are identified with the same manufacturer/model (ViewSonic Corporation 27").
One is using an HDMI output, supported by the onboard Intel graphics.
The other is using a Thunderbolt output (with a tbolt-to-dvi cable), supported by the integrated NVidia graphics adapter.
My laptop is an Alienware M17 R2
I had to install the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 to get the external monitors recognized initially

Why isn't the display ordering being preserved across reboots? Is there something I can do to address this (other than buying new cables of different lengths so that the monitors don't have to be rearranged :-) ). How can I provide more data to help diagnose this issue?
